# Empty class return when calling REST Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a REST Web Service that in all other ways is working how I want it to work.

I have a main class that contains contacts, in that class, there are 2 other lists of classes that I have created. 
My main class, and one of the lists comes through the call with all information intact. However, the second class is comming through as empty. It has each item in the list, but each list item is empty.

Web Service Function

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Login/{IQPid}/{Password}")]
        public IQP_Contacts Login(string IQPid, string password)
        {
            int iqpID = 0;
            try
            {
                iqpID = int.Parse(IQPid);
            }
            catch { return null; }
            IQP_Contacts contact = this.Repository.Contacts.Find(delegate(IQP_Contacts c) { return c.IqpID == iqpID; });
            if (contact.Password == password)
            {
                return contact;
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

Code calling the web service

```
           WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
            byte[] abc = proxy.DownloadData((new Uri("http://localhost:53468/IQP_Service.svc/Login/" + ID + "/" + password )));

            Stream strm = new MemoryStream(abc);
            DataContractSerializer obj = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IQP_Contacts));
            IQP_Contacts contact = (IQP_Contacts)obj.ReadObject(strm);
```

As you can see below, my webservice's class contains the information, but the the webpage does not

[image: Web Service]

[image: Website]

---

If anyone has any ideas, Please let me know. I am lost on this one. Something this simple shouldn't be this broken. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your DataContract's (IQP_Contacts) are the same on both client and server?

Comment: Yes, the webservice and website are in the same place and referencing the exact same class. Also, when calling a function just using a URI in the browser to get a XML reply, the Files return empty.

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past where when I debugged through visual studio, I saw values of my entities populated, but when passing the entity, the members were unpopulated.  I **think** the act of examining the property in visual studio triggers the entity to fetch its value (not sure if this is the correct term). If you were to put some print statements in your web service that simply accesses the property, you might find that your returned object will have its data populated (maybe).

Comment: That looks interesting. Although does it only matter when you have the class has children? I am not using children in this case. Just a list of the Files class within the IQP_Contacts class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the documentation about DataContractSerializer to see what does and does not get serialized by default: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx

It is hard to tell without seeing your classes. But  it is possible that your `Files` property is readonly (only has a `get` accesser with no `set`) then it would not get serialized.

It could also depend on if you have selectively applied `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` attributes on your classes. This affects the behavior of what DataContractSerializer will serialize/deserialize. You would need to  indicate that your "Files" property on IQP_RestWebService.Entitys.IQP_Contacts class is marked with a [DataMember] attribute and that you have a [DataContract] on the IQP_RestWebService.Entitys.Files class.

Comment: Thank you, the [datacontract] and [datamember] attributes I must of obviously overlooked when I created the class. And probably the one thing that I didnt think to look at when it didnt work.